# Register an addon in Episerver CMS 12

Tags: episerver, optimizely

Plugin UI are developed in a separate MVC project and CMS 12 is in another projects. Following is a test solution that just to explain the issue we are having.
[Solution structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM6SD.png)

Please consider followings

1. The  TestAddon project is a Simple MVC project with basic UI. We need to get this UI rendered in a CMS 12 Admin menu. We have created a menu provider as well.
2. Then build the TestAddon project and copied DLLs to CMS-> bin folder.
3. Created module/_protected folder and added TestAddon/TestAddon.zip
4. module.config was created as described in the documentation(https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/configuration/Configuring-moduleconfig/)

```
    <module productName="TestAddon" loadFromBin="false" tags="EPiServerModulePackage" clientResourceRelativePath="1.0.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="TestAddon" />
      <add assembly="TestAddon.Views" />
      </assemblies>
    
      <route url="{controller}/{action}" > 
        <defaults>
          <!--<add key="moduleArea" value="TestAddon" />-->
          <add key="controller" value="CustomAdminPage" />
          <add key="action" value="Index" />
        </defaults>
      </route>
    
      <clientResources>
        <!-- <add name="myscript" path="ClientResources/index.js" resourceType="Script" ></add> -->
      </clientResources>
    
    
      <clientModule>
        <moduleDependencies>
          <add dependency="CMS" />
          <add dependency="Shell"/>
           <add dependency="EPiServer.Cms.UI.Admin" type="RunAfter"/>
          <add dependency="EPiServer.Cms.UI.Settings" type="RunAfter"/> 
        </moduleDependencies>
        <requiredResources>
        </requiredResources>
      </clientModule>
    </module>
```

5. Set Auto discovery in startup file

`services.Configure<ProtectedModuleOptions>(x => x.AutoDiscovery = EPiServer.Shell.Configuration.AutoDiscoveryLevel.Modules);`

6. When we then start the project it is giving following error
   [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhvYz.png)
7. [Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSPzq.png)
8. When we removed the auto discovery setting form startup class. It works to build the project

Does anyone have experienced this?
Please point me in a correct direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to copy files to your sample project for local testing. You can add a project reference to your add-on project instead, then add this in your sample project's startup so the files are loaded correctly:

```cs
var moduleName = typeof(SomeClassInYourAddOn).Assembly.GetName().Name;

services.Configure<CompositeFileProviderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.BasePathFileProviders.Add(new MappingPhysicalFileProvider(
        $"/EPiServer/{moduleName}",
        string.Empty,
        Path.GetFullPath($"..\\..\\src\\{moduleName}")));
});

services.Configure<ProtectedModuleOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Items.Add(new ModuleDetails { Name = moduleName });
});
```

Not sure if this is needed, but I don't think protected modules are auto discovered. So if you have a configuration method in your add-on that consumers of your add-on need to call, then you can add this in the method:

```cs
var moduleName = typeof(SomeClassInYourAddOn).Assembly.GetName().Name;

services.Configure<ProtectedModuleOptions>(options =>
{
    if (!options.Items.Any(i => i.Name.Equals(moduleName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    {
        options.Items.Add(new ModuleDetails() { Name = moduleName });
    }
});
```

Then your add-on is added even if auto discovery is not enabled.

Comment: Your works when I have it in startup file in the CMS project it works to build and run the project. But I can't see a menu added in the admin menu. I have MenuProvider in the addon project. So how should I fix this to show the menu item? Also is there any way to do even this module registration from module project itself.i mean when installing the module.?

Comment: That's what the last code does, automatically adds the protected module. But not sure if it's needed. You still have to package up your module in a zip and include everything needed before distributing it. Well, I guess you don't have to use a zip, you can probably include all files directly in the NuGet package, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: If you only have one menu related to a controller, you can decorate the controller with `[MenuItem]` https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/user-interface/extending-the-navigation/adding-and-configuring-menu-items/.

Comment: Would be greate if some one can help me with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382419/configurecmsdefault-not-found-in-ihostbuilder-optimizelyepiserver-cms-12