# ConfigureCmsDefault() not found in IHostBuilder - Optimizely (EPiServer) CMS 12

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I had Optimizely (formerly Episerver) CMS version `12.3.1` in a project and I updated it to `12.4.0`. Now I'm getting the following error in **Program.cs** when trying to add the `.ConfigureCmsDefault()` call.

[image]

> Error CS1061  'IHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureCmsDefault' and no accessible extension method 'ConfigureCmsDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'IHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have the following package versions installed:

[image]

Does Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Also can't find 12.4.0 for EPiServer.CMS, it is still 12.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension method is called `ConfigureCmsDefaults` (you're missing an `s`).

You could update the `EPiServer.Framework` and `EPiServer.CMS.Core` packages to the latest version (`12.4.0`). The `EPiServer.CMS` package does not have dependencies to the most recent package versions yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ted! I Managed to get it worked. Actually in their documentation, they have different names in code and description. In code we have ConfigureCmsDefaults (With letter s) but in the description, we don't have the letter s. I copied the word from description, which was wrong. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, @NimeshAnuradha!